# Selecting digits from messy vector via gsub / regex

Tags: regex, r, string, replace, gsub

I'm working with a vector *vecA* corresponding to the one generated below:

```
vecA <- c("[  0, 10)", "[ 10, 20)", "[ 20, 30)", "[ 50, 60)", "[ 90,100]")
```

I would like to arrive at the *vecB* removing special characters and inserting hyphens, as in the sample generated below:

```
vecB <- c("0 - 10", "10 - 20", "20 - 30", "50 - 60", "90 - 100")
```

## Problem

I've the `gsub` syntax, that *almost* works:

```
vecB <- gsub(pattern =
                 "^(\\[{1})([[:blank:]]*)(\\d{1,2})([,])(.*)(\\d{2,3})([[:punct:]])$",
                          x = vecA, replacement = "\\3 - \\6")
```

The only problem is with the values `[ 90,100]` which are mistakenly transformed to **`90 - 00`** not to **`90 - 100`** as it should be ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rJ7nL3/1)).

Comment: I wonder if you are interested in where your regex is wrong. A hint: `(.*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use capture groups i.e. inside the `(..)` to get the numeric part and remove all others i.e. the non-numeric (`\\D+`).

In the pattern below, we match one or more non-numeric elements (`\\D+`- it includes the `[` and white space following it), then capture the one or more digits (`(\\d+)`), followed by matching the one or more non-numeri (`\\D+`- matches the `,` and white space following ), the second capture group of digits (`\\d+`)  followed by `.*` i.e it matches the rest of the string upto its end.  In the replacement, we specify the backreference (`\\1`) followed by space followed by `-` and the second backreference ('\2`).

```
sub('\\D+(\\d+)\\D+(\\d+).*', '\\1 - \\2', vecA)
#[1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

EDIT: Based on comments from @Wiktor Stribiżew

---

Or we can use `str_extract` from `library(stringr)` to extract the digits and then `paste` it together

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(vecA, '[0-9]+'), paste, collapse=' - ')
#[1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

Comment: I see I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: I wouldn't describe `.*` as *zero or more characters*. At the end of the pattern in R TRE regex, it means *match the rest of the string up to its end*.

Answer (score 2):

**1) sub/gsub** This can be broken into two simple sub/gsub calls.  The inner `gsub` replaces anything that is not a digit or comma with the empty string and the outer `sub` translates comma to space-minus-space.

```
sub(",", " - ", gsub("[^0-9,]", "", vecA))
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**2) one sub** To do it with one `sub`:

```
sub("^\\D*(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+)\\D*$", "\\1 - \\2", vecA)
## "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**3) substring/read.table**  This one does not use sub or gsub or any regular expressions:

```
with(read.table(text = substring(vecA, 2, nchar(vecA)-1), sep = ","), paste(V1, "-", V2))
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**3a)** This variation of (3) is slightly shorter:

```
with(read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", vecA)), paste(V1, "-", V2))
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**4) gsubfn** This extracts the capture groups and performs the indicated `paste`:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(vecA, "(\\d+)\\D*(\\d+)", ~ paste(x, "-", y), simplify = c)
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**4a)** Variation of (4) that uses `stapplyc` rather than `strapply`:

```
library(gsubfn)
sapply(strapplyc(vecA, "\\d+"), paste, collapse = " - ")
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**4b)** Variation of (4) that uses gsubfn rather than `strapply`:

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\D+", ~ if (grepl(",", x)) " - " else "", vecA)
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

**5) strsplit** This is another solution that does not use sub or gsub:

```
f <- function(x) {
  paste0(ifelse(x == ",", " - ", ifelse(x %in% 0:9, x, "")), collapse = "")
}
sapply(strsplit(vecA, ""), f)
## [1] "0 - 10"   "10 - 20"  "20 - 30"  "50 - 60"  "90 - 100"
```

Comment: didn't notice that someone else already gave an answer nearly identical to (2).

Answer (score 2):

Reminded me that I was solving the same problem of labeling intervals nicely. Here is my result, disregarding there is no regular expression in that:

```
library(dplyr)

# 1-9 by one, up to 75 by 5, up to 300 by 50, rest by 100
c(0:9, 
    seq(14, 50, by=5), 
    seq(59, 100, by=10), 
    seq(149, 300, by=50), 
    seq(400, 1000, by=100)) ->
  breaks

# create nice labels for the intervals
# assuming integral numbers will be cut by the breaks (hence the `l + 1`)
data.frame(l = breaks[1:length(breaks) - 1],
           r = breaks[2:length(breaks)]) %>%
               mutate(diff = r - l,
                      lab = ifelse(diff > 1, 
                                   paste0(l + 1, " - ", r), 
                                   as.character(r))) ->
  labs

# and cut() the data in `pos` colum getting directly the factors with
# nice names
d %>% mutate(bin=cut(pos, breaks, labels=labs$lab))
```